# Prototype/Scriptaculous Cycle (Slideshow) Plugin

Tags: plugins, prototypejs, slideshow, cycle, scriptaculous

I've got a bunch of websites that use a few Prototype/Scriptaculous plugins such as lightbox and modalbox, hence include references to these two libraries on various pages.

I now need to implement a slideshow on every page, and to follow suit, I need a Prototype cycle or slideshow plugin. The requirements are fairly simple:

1. images should fade-in/out every N seconds
2. four controls: prev, pause, play, next
3. i'd prefer to add images to the slideshow via JavaScript; not by adding too many  tags

Can any one suggest an existing plugin that can be customized easily and is not bloated like most of the other plugins.

Here is a jQuery plugin which provides similar functionality:
http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prototype Carousel](http://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/) is a lightweight plugin for Prototype and Scriptaculous. It's not quite as robust as the jQuery Cycle plugin, but it does the job.

If there's something that you want it to do that isn't built in (like [pause/play](http://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/issues/detail?id=13)), check out the "Issues" forum; there are several code patches and code suggestions there submitted by the community.